# Edit an echo output in "inline edit" style in php, mysql-

Tags: php, database, content-management-system, inline, edit

OK first of all hello to everyone, ill explain my question in the most clear way i can.

Im pulling an echo result from a database, using this simple line:

```
<?php echo $process ?>
```

what i need to do is, make that result editable, so when you click on it (or an edit link), you can just enter "edit mode" there and select an option from a dropdown list then save it to the database, without leaving that page at all.

Is this even possible?

This is my php code for connection and session

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
require_once('connection.php');
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result3 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SET NAMES UTF8;");
$result3 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM 
MXCustomer where mem_id='$id'");
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{ 
$cname=$row3['cname'];
$lname=$row3['lname'];
$rname=$row3['rname'];
$rposition=$row3['rposition'];
$csector=$row3['csector'];
$cproducts=$row3['cproducts'];
$process=$row3['process'];
}
?>
```

tried looking for an answer for this kind of need but i didnt found something useful, so any help will be appreciated.

My coding skill level isn´t high, i'm learning to make a cms from scratch, and this is proving difficult as such trivial thing for a basic cms.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will need to differentiate server side from client side handling. Also the nature of http request. It can be done with javascript at the client side.

Comment: Yes, it's possible - but not using PHP alone. You need  to use JS to handle the editing and sending of new data, then PHP to save it.

Comment: This code is for the "customer" profile page.

Can you guys direct me to some sort of documentation or example on the matter? thank you in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for recommendations/suggestions about guides/tutorials or other off-site resources are off-topic here on SO. You need to hit Google and do a lot of research.